# MySQL COUNT takes 11s, how to improve

Tags: mysql, indexing

I am trying to count the occurrence of sales.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT item, COUNT(item) FROM sales_raw
    GROUP BY item HAVING (count(item)>=1)
    ORDER BY COUNT(item) DESC
```

This query takes about eleven seconds on a table of about 500,000 rows. When I do an explain, I get:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  sales_raw   index   NULL    vendor_id   767 NULL    397431  Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Why does this query take so long and how can I improve this?

Comment: Can the column `item` take NULL values? If not, replace every `COUNT(item)` by `COUNT(*)`. You can also consider an index on `item`.

Comment: @VincentSavard: no, item will never be NULL.

Comment: shouldn't that be `select vendor_id...`

Comment: @juergend Thanks for pointing that out, I changed them all to `item`.

Comment: if possible remove the ORDER BY clause and order in code, that should also help

Comment: What's the difference if you remove `ORDER BY`?

Comment: What is the cardinality of `item`?  I.e. how many distinct values are there? Adding an index on `item` will help because it will eliminate the need to scan the table, and should return data already sorted, eliminating the sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Replace every `COUNT(item)` by `COUNT(*)`. The former checks if values in `item` are NULL, and not the latter.
2. If it is still not fast enough, add an index on your `item` column, which should make your query significantly faster.

Also, the `HAVING` clause seems useless as `COUNT(item)` cannot return 0, since the item wouldn't be in the table in the first place.

Comment: Assuming `item` is the primary key, what difference does it make if it's `COUNT(item)` or `COUNT(*)`?

Comment: @njk: According to his `explain` query, `vendor_id` is the primary key. If `item` was indeed the primay key, I assume MySQL just optimize the query itself.

Comment: @VincentSavard there does not appear to be an index on `item` at all; if there was, MySQL would have done an index scan instead.  All he needs to do is add an index on `item`.